# ionic + phonegap ( NOT cordova) give errors in installation does it even support phonegap?

Tags: cordova, window, ionic-framework

i installed the phonegap + nodejs + all that is needed to make  it work and it works great
now i like to install the ionic framework and use it in phonegap project but with no success.
i think its still looking for cordova .
what shell i do if i like to use it in phonegap ?
this is the error im getting while trying to Scaffold my First Ionic App

```
D:\dev\Mobile\PhoneGap>ionic start myFirstIonicApp
Creating Ionic app in folder D:\dev\Mobile\PhoneGap\myFirstIonicApp based on tabs project

Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-base/archive/master.zip
[=============================]  100%  0.0s

Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-tabs/archive/master.zip
[=============================]  100%  0.0s

Update config.xml
Initializing cordova project
'cordova' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Unable to add plugins. Perhaps your version of Cordova is too old. Try updating (npm install -g cordova), removing this project folder, and trying again. (CLI v1.2.8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use Cordova, because Cordova is the library with API's that phonegap uses. Phonegap only adds features like Phonegap build and Phonegap serve.

You will have to download Cordova with:
    `npm install -g cordova` and check if you can use the `cordova` command in your command prompt/terminal.

Comment: ok i beginner, i want to use the phonegap serve , so if i download cordova and develope cordova , i still can use phonegap serve?
wow why all this duplication's ?

Comment: There is not really duplication :) Cordova is the library that you will need to create the projects. `phonegap build` and `phonegap run android` for example are exactly the same as `cordova build`and `cordova run android`. Only to do a `phonegap serve` you will need to install both Phonegap and Cordova.

Comment: so if i understand right , i just develop for Cordova with all the Cordova CLI and when i want to use the phonegap serve i just use it ? 
it will know to use the Cordova project i created ?

Comment: Well, almost right. When you create a Phonegap project instead of a cordova project it Will create some additional configuration in the .cordova or .phonegap folder. That config is user when you do a phonegap serve. In short: Cordova project is compatible with phonegap, but not the other way around. However this compatibility problem is solved if You copy this config file from another project :)